# How can I keep two different font sizes on two different documents?

Tags: fonts, text-editor, document

I am using Xubuntu and I need to keep document A with font size 8 and B with with font size 12. If I save A with font size 8, this switches the font size to 8 for all the other documents, including B. Again, if I open B, turn the font to 12 and save the document this switches A too to 12, and so on.
This is rather boring. Somebody could tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Edit: I am using the plain text editor of Xubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the font size in a plain text editor will only change how your file is shown, but not, which font size it actually has (this can't be changed in a plain text file, it contains only the text, no formattings). If you want to have an document with different font sizes you have to use an office suite, for example [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/)